# Adding an image to a media bundle's field

Tags: entities, media

I am trying to add create a piece of new media with the following code. When visiting the media overview screen the media item is listed along with a thumbnail however when you edit the media item the file is not attached, although the file exists in the files area?

```
use Drupal\Core\Language\Language;
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media;

$data =     file_get_contents("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://plane.jpg',  FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);


$image_media = Media::create([
  'bundle' => 'image',
  'uid' => '1',
  'langcode' => Language::LANGCODE_DEFAULT,
  'status' => Media::PUBLISHED,
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id() ,
    'alt' => t('this is the alt text'),
    'title' => t('this is an image'),
  ],
]);
$image_media->save();
```

Comment: What happens when you load image_media directly after the save ? Is the file target_id there ?

Comment: Directly after the save the target_id is present and correct, however if i reload the media entity again straight away via Media::load the field is no longer attached.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a default language setup, Language::LANGCODE_DEFAULT will resolve to x-default.

Either:

- Set a default language
- Set the property manually, e.g, 'en' rather than Language::LANGCODE_DEFAULT
- Remove the line entirely